# Inserting Documents with MongoDB Java driver version 3

Tags: mongodb-java

We have some applications using MongoDB with Java driver (2.x version). In our apps we insert objects using the BasicDBObject such as:

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("title", "MongoDB").
            append("description", "database").
            append("likes", 100);
```

Looking at the docs of the Java Driver 3.0 I can see that another approach is used:

```
Document doc = new Document("name", "MongoDB")
               .append("type", "database")
               .append("count", 1)
               .append("info", new Document("x", 203).append("y", 102));
```

Is the BasicDBObject deprecated in the version 3.0? (hope not, we have to change all our code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to use DBObject with the 3.0 API.  Existing code should (mostly) work when bumping to the 3.0 driver.  There are various advantages to switching to the new APIs but that's something you can do at your leisure over time.